# Google Analytics Android SDK Campaign Measurement Special Content

Tags: android, google-analytics

I want receive special data in my android app, using 'Google Analytics Campaign Measurement', when the app was installed.

So, my questions are:

1. Can I do this using `utm_content` parameter?
2. Can I use custom parameter in 'Google Play URL referrer parameter'
   for my goal? Will I receive this parameter in my app? For example,
   my url is:
   https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.app&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dcpc%26utm_term%3Dpodcast%252Bapps%26utm_content%3DdisplayAd1%26utm_campaign%3Dpodcast%252Bgeneralkeywords%26MY_CUSTOM_PARAMETER%3DMY_DATA

Answer (score 0):

Only the following utm parameters will be passed over to Google Analytics for campaign on Android: `utm_id`, `utm_campaign`, `utm_content`, `utm_medium`, `utm_source` and `utm_term`. Custom provided parameters will be discarded. You can use `utm_content` (passed as campaign content  ["cc"](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cc) parameter to Google Analytics) or `utm_term` (passed as campaign keyword ["ck"](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ck) parameter). Campaign content should be passed verbatim from Android to Google Analytics and should appear in your report.